# How do I use the await keyword?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following "test" method:

```
public async Task<TitaniumUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
{
    long id;

    if (!long.TryParse(userId, out id))
        return null;

    return new TitaniumUser(id);
}
```

And I am calling it like:

```
var test = await userManager.FindByIdAsync("123");
```

But I am getting the following message:

> the 'await' operator can only be used in a method or lambda marked with the 'async' modifier

I would really apreciate any help on solving this matter.

Comment: That looks like a very clear error message to be honest..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your calling method must be marked as `async`:

```
public async Task Caller() {
    // this method is marked async
    var test = await userManager.FindByIdAsync("123");
}
```

`async` and `await` are a pair. You cannot use `await` within a method if it isn't marked `async`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler tell you what's wrong...

> the 'await' operator can only be used in a method or lambda marked with the 'async' modifier

'await' operator can only be used **in** NOT with. The async method is marked with the keyword, that it will return from the method without full completion.

You try to make a synchronous call asynchronous just by adding the await keyword in front of the Method-Call.

Your FindByIdAsync should contains code asynchronously and return the Task.

`TaskCompletionSource<T>` may helpful for the start.

Comment: Thank you.
I was misreading the IN part.. :(